# How to change jade variable dynamically with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

For example in my file index.jade I have:

```html
extends layout

block varScope
  -var selected = 'Home';
  -var isEmpty = 'false';
  
body
   button(onclick='changeState()') Click
  
   script.
     function changeState(){
       // change isEmpty variable here to true -- how to ?
     }
```

It is possible to setup my pug/jade variable with javascript?
If not, what alternatives do I have please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, we know that directly, it is impossible, but I found out a way how to do it with JS. I know that this is maybe not official and correct behavior and things like this could be done with for example [facebook-passport](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-facebook), but for those who need quick tests and need save time with reading new SW module documentation, can do this:

As I mentioned in a comment, it is possible to make it with URL. In my server file **app.js** I need to configure my route, that will send to my same view (to pug/jade) my variable that is obtained through URL from javascript of the view page:

```
app.get('/home/user/:id', function(req, res) {

  var id = req.params.id;

  // do the DB or other stuff here

  console.log('I received in the server user id from JS(FB GraphAPI): '+ id);

  app.locals.isEmpty= id

  res.redirect('/home');

});

app.get('/home', function(req, res) {

  res.render('home', { isEmpty: app.locals.id }); // or if you want send anything

});
```

And I have this in my **home.jade** file:

```
extends layout

block varScope
     -var selected = 'Home';

-var isEmpty = 'true'; // here will be setted variable from JS

body
   button(onclick='changeState()') Click

   script.
     function changeState(){
          window.location.assign("http://localhost:3000/home/user/34sfd")
     }
```

Now in my home.jade I have my variable from JS:

> -var isEmpty = 34sfd

The price for doing it like this is that in result the manual page refresh will occur.

For those, who were looking for sending this variable to extension jade/pug file (**layout.jade**), you even do not have to send it as object, you can easily pick it now from set of local variables:

```
-var isEmpty= locals.isEmpty
```

Answer (score 4):

No, what you're asking to do here isn't possible.  Pug is run on the server and JavaScript is run on the client in the browser.  Once the pug template is rendered on the server that's it, there's no more pug in the process.

What you can do is preload the variable name using pug:

```
script.
  var isEmpty = !{isEmpty};
  function changeState(){
    // change isEmpty variable here to true -- how to ?
  }
```

Or if you have a more complex object you can stringify it before you pass it to the template:

```
script.
  var user = !{user};
  function changeUserName(){
    user.name = ...
  }
```

Comment: yess this all I well know now.. ok, it is impossible then... I even tried localStorage, or pug preload functions ... but as you said, the client and server are too far viceversa... isn't there an option to do it somehow through routing? For example client JS will send parameters through URL to route which will set that pug variable after next load of that page? ... (I am trying to do FB login with GraphAPI , I have obtained successfully session token, but do not know how to change my pug menu items, how pug would know... I tried many tutorials with 12 hours working now but without success...)

Comment: I think you're trying to do advanced web development before you have the basics understood.